# Concatenate lines of form input into a single line

Tags: python, django, concatenation

I have a HTML form, user will input here text (with lines), like this :

```
How are you?
I am fine. 
Thank you!
```

In the server side, I will get that input by :

```
input = request.POST['input']
```

And then I will to concatenate them into a single line like this :

```
How are you? I am fine.Thank you!
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work :

```
 input = request.POST['input']
 input = input.rstrip('\n')
 print(input) #print to test the concatenation
```

Please help me! Thank you!

Comment: Does `input.replace('\n', '')` help?

Answer (score 1):

`newstring = input.replace('\n', '')` should work

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
" ".join(input.split("\n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Harrison and Cychih for your answer, I tried however, they don't work. The solution I found is this :

```
newstring = input1.replace('\r\n', ' ')
```

It's

```
'\r\n'
```

not

```
'\n'
```

When I put in the form 3 lines like this ;

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

Here is the output of the request.POST

```
<QueryDict: {'input1': ['Line 1 \r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3\r\n'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['tvC0ISHPNEkdQzocuVRnhJCp5yadDkgC5wf832blrpYPP0MZVV1iNY5bI2cYXsA4'], 'output1': [' ']}>
```

I don't know why new line is set as \r\n but it's the way it is .

Thank you again for your help!